# How to use FLow XO and API.ai together in one bot

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es, telegram-bot, chatbot

I have a question. Is it possible to use both flowXO and API.ai together and single-time in one bot? If so, how to implement it?

Comment: No, you can't. Because they are different service.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Flow XO to API.ai To understand a user’s intent.
Send HTTP request to APi.ai. By Post method you can pass query with some authentication data in header. Dialogflow resolve this query and give you response in JSON format. You can directly use this data in flow.

You can find step by step instruction in below link.

[Using Flow XO with Dialogflow](https://medium.com/flowxo/using-flow-xo-with-api-ai-86f59e24cda6)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Thank you for your comments, i will take care of all this things that you have mention here and will improve my self.